# Is there a free temperature monitor program that works on a 2014 Retina MBP?

Tags: mac-appstore

Is there a free temperature monitor program that works on a 2014 Retina MBP? I don't need fancy features, fan control, etc. Just temperatures are fine.

All of the ones I've found in the App Store and elsewhere are paid, and the only free ones I've found don't work with new machines.

Comment: I have a couple of free temperature monitoring utilities on my MacBook Pro Retina that I use. One of which also cycles fans up/down for me based on my own criteria. I don't understand the question I guess?

Comment: I haven't found any.. I'd love a link (& feel free to close the question).

Comment: If you want to edit this to explain what you want to do, people can answer and if you don't specify free it helps everyone with e same problem and not just those with more free time than free money.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear what I wanted to do. I thought something was impossible, so I asked why. Turns out it's not impossible. Either way I re-wrote the question.

Comment: For me it was the speculation involving conspiracies involving App Store policies or some limitation imposed on developers, pontification about laptops catching fire and the whining about how plentiful unrelated software for guitar tuning is on other platforms.

Comment: My post contained neither speculation nor pontification. I was legitimately surprised not to see free temperature and guitar tuner apps and was wondering what the reason was. My off-hand remark about melting the laptop comes from personal experience with heat damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really an app, but there is a Widget for on your Dashboard that can display diagnostics information like the temperature. One of them I personally prefer is iStat Pro, you can find it [on Softonic](http://istat-pro.softonic.com/mac) (the official site is offline). Hit the large green "Descargar Gratis" (Free Download) button and right-click > open the file from your downloads folder. It will be installed in your Dashboard, where it will show temperatures by default. Confirmed by me to work on the latest (late 2013) 15" rMBP.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Ironically I had previously found and used the _app_ version of iStat Pro, but it was only a 14-day trial. I somehow missed the widget version.

Comment: Update as of September 2015: it's still available for download and it still works great on Yosemite.